# Google Sheet Script server error on getNamedRanges()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, server-error

While writing a Google Apps Script for Google Sheets to delete Named Ranges that have been orphaned by deleting the target they reference, an unexpected "server error" occurred. Can someone please tell me how to avoid it?

EDIT: Please note that in addition to solving the attached demonstration script, I seek a general solution for every time the routine SpreadsheetApp.getNamedRanges() is called. I will deploy a command to remove orphaned range names from any Google Spreadsheet. It will be part of the NamedRanges routines in dlbTools which is already available in the Google Add-ons Store at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dlbtools./ochdleihpppeoboanknpbmabbdjfihjj.

I wrote a Google Spreadsheet that demonstrates it, producing the message:
 - "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 8, file "Code")".
This spreadsheet is available publicly at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IKwGb9guw5Ud1q2YJj3Ao1yjjIvMGv35Pcpe_lyq48I/edit?usp=sharing

The error occurs:

- When method SpreadsheetApp.getNamedRanges() is called.
- Only after deleting a row that had been referenced in a Named Range using a full-row style reference.
- Only if the Named Range reference is like "1:1" instead of "A1:B1".
- Only after the referenced row has been deleted causing the Named Range to refer to "#REF!".

Steps to demonstrate this unexpected server error by using the Google Spreadsheet are:

- Select menu item Tools > Script editor...
- Switch to tab "Find Orphans Scripts"
- Select menu item Run > findOrphans
- Observe the red bar saying, "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 8, file "Code")"
- Select menu item View > Logs
- Select menu item View > Execution transcript

Here is the test script that demonstrates the server error:
    function findOrphans() {

```
// Helper function logs Named Range names and references.
  var logNamedRanges = function (scenario) {
    Logger.log('Logging named ranges for scenario: ' + scenario);
    Logger.log('In logNamedRanges() before call to getNamedRanges()');
    var namedRanges = ss.getNamedRanges();
    Logger.log('In logNamedRanges() after call to getNamedRanges()');
    var names = namedRanges.map(function (nr){return nr.getName() + ' --> ' + nr.getRange().getA1Notation();});
    Logger.log('\n' + names.join('\n'));
  } 

// Helper function alters Named Ranges to full row references.
// That is, "A1:B1" becomes "1:1".
  var changeRangeReferencesToFullRow = function () {
    Logger.log('In changeRangeReferencesToFullRow() before call to getNamedRanges()');
    var namedRanges = shtTest.getNamedRanges();
    Logger.log('In changeRangeReferencesToFullRow() after call to getNamedRanges()');
    for (var i = 0; i < namedRanges.length; i++) {
      var n = namedRanges[i].getRange().getA1Notation();
      var num = n.charAt(1);
      var fullRowA1Notation = num + ':' + num;
      var fullRowNameRange = shtTest.getRange(fullRowA1Notation);
      namedRanges[i].setRange(fullRowNameRange);
    }
    Logger.log('Successfully changed Named Ranges to full row references');
  }

// Helper function creates test sheet by copying sheet Static and
// creates Named Ranges for each of the first two rows.
  var setupTestSheet = function () {
    if (ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Static') != null) {
      // Test sheet already exists, so delete it.
      ss.deleteSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Static'));
      Logger.log('Deleted existing copy of test sheet');
    }
    // Activate sheet Static, duplicate it, and grab reference to it.
    shtStatic.activate();
    ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
    shtTest = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Static');
    // Create or update Named Nanges pointing to the first two rows.
    ss.setNamedRange('row1Name', shtTest.getRange('1:1'));
    ss.setNamedRange('row2Name', shtTest.getRange('2:2'));
    Logger.log('Successfully set up test sheet');
  }

// Helper function runs test sequence.
function doTest (whichPass) {
  Logger.log('\n\nStarting test using ' + whichPass + '\n\n');
  setupTestSheet();
  if (whichPass.slice(0,3) == '1:1') {
  // next line is only difference between the passes
    changeRangeReferencesToFullRow();
  }
  logNamedRanges('Before row delete')
  shtTest.deleteRow(1);
  if (whichPass.slice(-5) == 'error') {
  // next line stops test before error occurs
    Logger.log('Halted test to avoid error');
    return;
  }
  logNamedRanges('After row delete')
  Logger.log('Finished test using ' + whichPass );
}

// Create variables that will be available to helper functions.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shtStatic = ss.getSheetByName('Static');
  var shtTest;

// Execute test sequence three times.
  doTest('A1:B1 style references');
  doTest('1:1 style references with stop before server error');
  doTest('1:1 style references without stopping');
}
```

## Test with Sheets API

@Tanaike's suggestion of using the Sheets API helps because it successfully retrieves the list of Named Ranges where the SpreadsheetAPP call fails. Unfortunately, it does not include the ones of most interest—the orphans.

The demonstration Spreadsheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IKwGb9guw5Ud1q2YJj3Ao1yjjIvMGv35Pcpe_lyq48I/edit?usp=sharing now includes an additional script file called `trySheetsAPI.gs`. The comments at the top tell how to identify the additional code that tests the Sheets API. While I appreciate this helpful and interesting suggestion, it still does not allow me to write a general purpose orphan deletion routine.

Comment: I think I answered this myself. I found the Google Issue Tracker system. It contains this item as: https://issuetracker.google.com/36764977 Calling getNamedRanges() always results in "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."

Answer (score 3):

How about this consideration? I don't know whether this is the best. I'm sorry.

### Modification points :

It was found that when the namedrange was updated, the error occurs. The flow of your script is as follows.

When `setupTestSheet()` was run, the namedranges are defined by `ss.setNamedRange('row1Name', shtTest.getRange('1:1'))` and `ss.setNamedRange('row2Name', shtTest.getRange('2:2'))` as follows. Following value was retrieved using Sheet API.

```
{
  "namedRanges": [
    {
      "namedRangeId": "#####",
      "name": "row1Name",
      "range": {
        "endColumnIndex": 26,
        "startRowIndex": 0,
        "endRowIndex": 1,
        "sheetId": #####,
        "startColumnIndex": 0
      }
    },
    {
      "namedRangeId": "#####",
      "name": "row2Name",
      "range": {
        "endColumnIndex": 26,
        "startRowIndex": 1,
        "endRowIndex": 2,
        "sheetId": #####,
        "startColumnIndex": 0
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

At this time, respective namedranges are defined on Spreadsheet as follows. This can be seen at Spreadsheet using your browser.

```
row1Name 'Copy of Static'!A1:Z1
row2Name 'Copy of Static'!A2:Z2
```

Here, when `shtTest.deleteRow(1)` is run, above namedranges change as follows.

```
row1Name #REF
row2Name 'Copy of Static'!A2:Z2
```

Under this situation, **no error occurs** at `var namedRanges = shtTest.getNamedRanges()`.

At `setupTestSheet()`, both `ss.setNamedRange('row1Name', shtTest.getRange('1:1'));` and `ss.setNamedRange('row2Name', shtTest.getRange('2:2'));` work fine.

But, `changeRangeReferencesToFullRow()` doesn't work completely. When `changeRangeReferencesToFullRow()` runs, namedranges are as follows. It is found that the column data is lost.

```
{
  "namedRanges": [
    {
      "namedRangeId": "#####",
      "name": "row1Name",
      "range": {
        "startRowIndex": 0,
        "endRowIndex": 1,
        "sheetId": #####
      }
    },
    {
      "namedRangeId": "#####",
      "name": "row2Name",
      "range": {
        "startRowIndex": 1,
        "endRowIndex": 2,
        "sheetId": #####
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

At this time, respective namedranges are defined on Spreadsheet as follows.

```
row1Name 'Copy of Static'!1:1
row2Name 'Copy of Static'!2:2
```

Under this situation, **no error occurs** at `var namedRanges = shtTest.getNamedRanges()`.

Here, when `shtTest.deleteRow(1)` is run, above namedranges become as follows.

```
row1Name #REF
row2Name 'Copy of Static'!2:2
```

Under this situation, **the error occurs** at `var namedRanges = shtTest.getNamedRanges()`. So when `shtTest.deleteRow(1)` is used, `row1Name #REF` has to be removed or updated.

These indicates that the range like `1:1` and `2:2` might not be suitable for the namedrange of `SpreadsheetApp`.

### Workaround :

The workaround reflected above consideration is as follows.

1. After the row was removed by `deleteRow()`, redefine the namedrange of the row using `ss.setNamedRange('row1Name', shtTest.getRange('1:1'))` and `ss.setNamedRange('row2Name', shtTest.getRange('2:2'))`.
2. Remove the namedrange of the row removed by `deleteRow()` using following modified script. Modify only `doTest()` as following script.

#### Script :

```
function doTest (whichPass) {
  Logger.log('\n\nStarting test using ' + whichPass + '\n\n');
  setupTestSheet();

  var r = shtTest.getNamedRanges(); // <--- Added

  if (whichPass.slice(0,3) == '1:1') {
  // next line is only difference between the passes
    changeRangeReferencesToFullRow();
  }
  logNamedRanges('Before row delete')

  var dummy = [i.remove() for each (i in r) if (i.getName() == "row1Name")]; // <--- Added

  shtTest.deleteRow(1);
  if (whichPass.slice(-5) == 'error') {
  // next line stops test before error occurs
    Logger.log('Halted test to avoid error');
    return;
  }
  logNamedRanges('After row delete')
  Logger.log('Finished test using ' + whichPass );
}
```

In my environment, above scripts works fine. If these don't work at your environment. Feel free to tell me.

## For additional question

How about use of Sheet API?

In order to remove orphaned range names from any Google Spreadsheet, you can use `namedRangeId`. `namedRangeId` is the individual ID for each namedrange. By using this, the orphaned range names can be removed.

In order to use `namedRangeId`,it uses Sheet API. So please enable Sheet API for Advanced Google Services and Google API Console.

Google Sheets API v4 https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/

Advanced Google Services https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

### Sample script :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var r = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ss.getId(), {fields: "namedRanges(name,namedRangeId)"});
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(
  {"requests": [{
      "deleteNamedRange": {
        "namedRangeId": [i.namedRangeId for each (i in r.namedRanges) if (i.name == "### name ###")][0]
  }}]},
  ss.getId()
);
```

The flow is as follows.

1. Using `Sheets.Spreadsheets.get()`, retrieve name and namedrangeID.
2. The namedrangeID matched to the name is removed.

In the case of use of Sheet API, if  the range data is lost, although `getNamedRanges()` occurs the error, Sheet API can retrieve the namedrange.

If I misunderstand your additional question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough analysis and clear explanation, Tanaike. I especially appreciate learning the coding technique in your "var dummy =" line which I've never seen before.

While your workaround solves the demonstration script, it still leaves open the broader question of a general solution. Since I didn't mention that before, I edited the question to add it. Maybe you will also be able to help with that. If so, I will be even happier. Thank you again.

Comment: @Dave Bezaire I updated my answer, just now. Please confirm it.

Comment: Thank you, @Tanaike, for your additional suggestions. Again they are informative and helpful. Unfortunately they still do not help me find the orphans as described in my edit to your message. Thanks again!

Comment: @Dave Bezaire Please add your additional information to your own question. And I couldn't find ``trySheetsAPI.gx`` you say. So I cannot try to run your script. I went to your spreadsheet sample, but I couldn't open it. Where can I find your sample script?

Comment: You deleted my comments? Did you keep a copy of them someplace? Maybe cached someplace?

Comment: I put comments at end of my original question with another link to the Spreadsheet.

Comment: @Dave Bezaire I don't remove it. But your additional comments to my answer had been rejected. You can see it https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17008846 I confirmed your additional comments on your question just now. I cannot find ``trySheetsAPI.gs``. Where can I find your sample script?