# How to create list of all named ranges - empty or defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking to use Google App Scripts to return all named ranges and then remove those with empty or #REF values.

I've tried numerous endpoints to query the named ranges but these responses only return defined ranges.

Example code snippet:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges();
  var tmpArrays = [];

  ranges.forEach(function(range) {
    if(range.getRange() !== null) {
    tmpArrays.push(range.getName(), range.getRange());
    range.remove();
    }
  });

  tmpArrays.forEach(function(addRange) {
    ss.setNamedRange(addRange[0], addRange[1]);
  });
```

I'd be expecting a list of all named ranges in the spreadsheet, defined or not.

Comment: Have you tried all the suggested answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+%23REF+named+ranges)

Comment: Hey @TheMaster - I have, two issues I see on the posts here: GAS returns defined namedRanges and/or requires you to know the name of the range in order to delete. My approach at the moment will be to return an array from Chrome Console based on the pane fly-out of the named ranges.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601751) answer seems to suggest  API can retrieve even orphans. Have you tried that too?

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

This will find and list all named ranges, their location and their values.  At least it did so for my named ranges.

```
function findAllNamedRanges() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var nrA=ss.getNamedRanges();
  var html="<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style>";
  for(var i=0;i<nrA.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('Name: %s Range: %s Sheet: %s <br />',nrA[i].getName(),nrA[i].getRange().getA1Notation(),nrA[i].getRange().getSheet().getName());
    var vA=nrA[i].getRange().getValues();
    var row=nrA[i].getRange().getRow();
    var col=nrA[i].getRange().getColumn();
    if(vA.length>1) {
      html+="<table><tr><th>Row</th><th>Col</th><th>Value</th></tr>";
      for(var j=0;j<vA.length;j++) {
        html+="<tr>";
        for(var k=0;k<vA[j].length;k++) {
          html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td>',row + j,col + k,vA[j][k]);
        }
        html+="</tr>"
      }
      html+='</table><br /><hr><br />';
    }      
    if(vA.length==1) {
      html+=Utilities.formatString('row: %s, col: %s value: %s <br /><hr>',row,col,vA[0][0]);
    }
    if(!vA) {
      html+="undefined <br /><hr>";
    }
  }
  Logger.log(html);
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Named Ranges");
}
```

This version also removes any named range with "#REF" in any of their cells.

```
function findAllNamedRanges() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var nrA=ss.getNamedRanges();
  var html="<style>th,td{border:1px solid black;}</style>";
  for(var i=0;i<nrA.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('Name: %s Range: %s Sheet: %s <br />',nrA[i].getName(),nrA[i].getRange().getA1Notation(),nrA[i].getRange().getSheet().getName());
    var vA=nrA[i].getRange().getValues();
    var row=nrA[i].getRange().getRow();
    var col=nrA[i].getRange().getColumn();
    if(vA.length>1) {
      html+="<table><tr><th>Row</th><th>Col</th><th>Value</th><th>Value</th></tr>";
      for(var j=0;j<vA.length;j++) {
        html+="<tr>";
        for(var k=0;k<vA[j].length;k++) {

          html+=Utilities.formatString('<td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td>',row + j,col + k,vA[j][k],(vA[j][k]=="#REF")?"Removed":"OK");
          if(vA[j][k]=="#REF") {
            nrA[i].remove;
            continue;
          }
        }
        html+="</tr>"
      }
      html+='</table><br /><hr><br />';
    }      
    if(vA.length==1) {

      html+=Utilities.formatString('row: %s, col: %s value: %s Status: %s<br /><hr>',row,col,vA[0][0],(vA[0][0]=="#REF")?"Removed":"OK");
      if(vA[0][0]=="#REF") {
        nrA[i].remove();
        continue;
      }
    }
    if(!vA) {
      html+="undefined <br /><hr>";
    }
  }
  Logger.log(html);
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Named Ranges");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have found out what happened since the time you posted, but there is an error in your script: you push 2 elements in the array, not an array of 2 elements.

**Fixed script:**

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges();
  var tmpArrays = [];

  ranges.forEach(function(range) {
    if(range.getRange() !== null) {
    tmpArrays.push([range.getName(), range.getRange()]); // <<<
    range.remove();
    }
  });

  tmpArrays.forEach(function(addRange) {
    ss.setNamedRange(addRange[0], addRange[1]);
  });
```